# ui-grid i18nService messy code with non-english characters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angular-translate

I am using angular ui-grid's i18nService. And it displays some messy code like
"è¡Œæ¯é¡µ" when I set current language to some language with non english character such as Chinese, Korean and something else.

But for the headers and cells which I use angular translate, everything display very well. I guess it maybe some setting problem, but I just have no clue.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set current language to Chinese.

code:

```
// set pagenation current language

i18nService.setCurrentLang('zh-cn');
```

you can also visit this page:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/104_i18n

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes I did this and it give me messy code. And the same for other language with non-english character.

Comment: you also import two js files ui-i18n.js, zh-cn.js to your html, these two ones are in the folder i18n

Comment: Hi. I tried it but the browser still give me the mess code.

Comment: I think it may not be the problem the code bcz it just a simple setting, can you think of any other possible factors may affect the result? I just have no clue

Comment: do u have a plunker? i have come with this question a few months ago, and then i solved it. if you have a plunker, it would be more easily to find the answer

Comment: Thank you! I solved it, it is because the encoding setting of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I got the anwser. It's the encoding problem of the browser. The encoding should be set to Unicode(UTF-8), if it not working, clear cache first and try again.